# delay in alarm, Alarm manager not triggering at correct time

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I found many answers to this question but none of them worked for me. I'm getting delay in the alarm. I am looking to set a repeated alarm. This is the code I have tried so far.

Alarm Code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
MyDatabase myDatabase = 
Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),MyDatabase.class,"AlarmDB")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();

Alarm alarm = new Alarm(newID,title.getText().toString(),timeis,"on",calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        myDatabase.dao().alarmInsertion(alarm);
        startAlarm(calendar,newID,alarm);
    
    private void startAlarm(Calendar c ,Long id,Alarm alarm) {
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlaramReceiver.class);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putSerializable("alarm",(Serializable)alarm);
            intent.putExtra("DATA",args);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id.intValue(), intent, 0);
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        }
```

broadcast receiver

```
public class AlaramReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        MyDatabase myDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, MyDatabase.class, "AlarmDB")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
        Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("DATA");
        Alarm alarm = (Alarm) args.getSerializable("alarm");
        Toast.makeText(context, alarm.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
        NotificationCompat.Builder nb = notificationHelper.getChannelNotification(alarm.getTitle());
        notificationHelper.getManager().notify(1, nb.build());
        Uri alarmuri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        if (alarmuri == null) {
            alarmuri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmuri);
        ringtone.play();

    }

}
```

Comment: By now, there is no API to match your need except AlarmManager.setExact(). It is not repeating, so when you receive Intent in your AlarmReceiver, you can set another alarm for future. link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)

Answer (score 1):

So as you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) in the official docs, since Android Kitkat 19 Alarm behavior has been change and there is basically no direct way to schedule an exact repeating alarm.

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) alarm
> delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize
> wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications
> which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long,
> android.app.PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long,
> android.app.PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is
> earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in
> which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

As a workaround you can set an exact alarm and on trigger of this alarm schedule a new exact alarm again.

For avoiding different Android version handling yourself, you can use `AlarmManagerCompat` and use method `setExact()`

e.g.

```
val intent = Intent(context,  AlarmReceiver::class.java)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

AlarmManagerCompat.setExact(alarmManager, AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, whenToTrigger, pendingIntent)
```

And in your broadcast receiver schedule an exact alarm again.

```
class AlarmReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

            //here schedule an exact alarm again.

            val intent = Intent(context,  AlarmReceiver::class.java)
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            AlarmManagerCompat.setExact(alarmManager, AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, whenToTrigger, pendingIntent)

        }
    }
```

> Note: only alarms for which there is a strong demand for exact-time
> * delivery (such as an alarm clock ringing at the requested time) should be
> * scheduled as exact.  Applications are strongly discouraged from using exact
> * alarms unnecessarily as they reduce the OS's ability to minimize battery use.